# SOME fonts and CSS work, SOME don't??? - Heroku React app

Tags: css, reactjs, heroku

Some styles on my website made with create-react-app at https://explore-welly.herokuapp.com/ are not working on other devices. For instance, the homepage SHOULD look like this, which has the correct CSS styling both locally and on Heroku on my laptop which I worked on the site.

[image]

However, when I open it on other devices, eg. my iPhone 6 on Safari, it looks mangled. Like this:

[image]

Yuck. I also opened it on Safari on another laptop, and the FONTS come in but like above the sun icon  and temperature are out of place.

I am importing the App.css file into every React component. Weirdly enough, SOME styles come in from the App.css, eg. box shadows on each shop in the 'Shop' page. So why on earth is a simple margin not applying to the weather section?

I'm using both Bootstrap and Reactstrap in conjunction with my custom styles. I am also doing a lot of overriding of bootstrap with !important and all that. I'm starting to debate whether this is a Heroku issue.

Here is the HTML and CSS for the weather:

```
<div className="weather-panel bg-transparent border-0 text-center" onClick={this.toggle}>
          <img className="weather-icon" src={require(`../../images/weather-icons/${this.props.weather.weatherIcon}.png`)} />
          <div className="weather-info text-white text-left">
            <h2>{this.props.weather.airvisualInfo.current.weather.tp}°C</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
.weather-panel {
  width: 140px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.weather-panel:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.weather-icon {
  width: 70px;
  float: left;
}

.weather-info {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.weather-info h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.weather-info h5 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.weather-description {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:800i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Welly</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my repo for reference: https://github.com/rlyhan/Welly-Site

Note: The App.css file is in client/src. The weather info is under client/src/components/modals.

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed the font issue. I was using the Fira Sans font from Google Fonts, which is in a woff2 format. Which apparently does not work on Safari. So I had to download the font, which came as a .zip of TFF files. I then placed the TFF file in a fonts folder and included it in my CSS like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  src: url('./fonts/FiraSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
```

As for the CSS of the weather... it turns out that the Dev Tools display of an iPhone 6 does not match up to the actual result shown on an iPhone 6. So I had to make a few adjustments to the CSS to get it working. In particular I added this media query for that weather part:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 235px) {

  .weather-icon {
    float: none !important;
  }

  .weather-info {
    float: none !important;
  }

}
```